# How the Look-ahead and Look-behind concept supports such Zero-Width Assertions concept in Regex of Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

I just gone through the concept `Zero-Width Assertions` from the documentation. And some quick questions comes into my mind-

- ***why such name `Zero-Width Assertions`?***
- ***How the `Look-ahead` and `look-behind` concept supports such
  `Zero-Width Assertions` concept?***
- ***What such `?<=s`,`<!s`,`=s`,`<=s` - 4 symbols are instructing inside the pattern? can you help me here to focus to understand what is actually going on***

I also tried some tiny codes to understand the logic, but not that much confident with the output of those:

```
irb(main):001:0> "foresight".sub(/(?!s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresee"
irb(main):002:0> "foresight".sub(/(?=s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresight"
irb(main):003:0> "foresight".sub(/(?<=s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresee"
irb(main):004:0> "foresight".sub(/(?<!s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresight"
```

Can anyone help me here to understand?

**EDIT**

*Here i have tried two snippets one with "Zero-Width Assertions" concepts as below:*

```
irb(main):002:0> "foresight".sub(/(?!s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresee"
```

*and the other is without "Zero-Width Assertions" concepts as below:*

```
irb(main):003:0> "foresight".sub(/ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresee"
```

Both the above produces same output,now internally how the both `regexp` move by their own to produce output- could you help me to visualize?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Regular expressions match from left to right, and move a sort of "cursor" along the string as they go.  If your regex contains a regular character like `a`, this means: "if there's a letter `a` in front of the cursor, move the cursor ahead one character, and keep going.  Otherwise, something's wrong; back up and try something else."  So you might say that `a` has a "width" of one character.

A "zero-width assertion" is just that: it *asserts* something about the string (i.e., doesn't match if some condition doesn't hold), but it doesn't move the cursor forwards, because its "width" is zero.

You're probably already familiar with some simpler zero-width assertions, like `^` and `$`.  These match the start and end of a string.  If the cursor isn't at the start or end when it sees those symbols, the regex engine will fail, back up, and try something else.  But they don't actually move the cursor forwards, because they don't match characters; they only check where the cursor is.

Lookahead and lookbehind work the same way.  When the regex engine tries to match them, it checks *around* the cursor to see if the right pattern is ahead of or behind it, but in case of a match, it doesn't move the cursor.

Consider:

```
/(?=foo)foo/.match 'foo'
```

This will match!  The regex engine goes like this:

1. Start at the beginning of the string: `|foo`.
2. The first part of the regex is `(?=foo)`.  This means: only match if `foo` appears after the cursor.  Does it?  Well, yes, so we can proceed.  But the cursor *doesn't move*, because this is zero-width.  We still have `|foo`.
3. Next is `f`.  Is there an `f` in front of the cursor?  Yes, so proceed, and move the cursor past the `f`: `f|oo`.
4. Next is `o`.  Is there an `o` in front of the cursor?  Yes, so proceed, and move the cursor past the `o`: `fo|o`.
5. Same thing again, bringing us to `foo|`.
6. We reached the end of the regex, and nothing failed, so the pattern matches.

On your four assertions in particular:

- `(?=...)` is "lookahead"; it asserts that `...` *does* appear after the cursor.

  ```
  1.9.3p125 :002 > 'jump june'.gsub(/ju(?=m)/, 'slu')
   => "slump june"
  ```

  The "ju" in "jump" matches because an "m" comes next.  But the "ju" in "june" doesn't have an "m" next, so it's left alone.

  Since it doesn't move the cursor, you have to be careful when putting anything after it.  `(?=a)b` will never match anything, because it checks that the next character is `a`, then *also* checks that the *same* character is `b`, which is impossible.
- `(?<=...)` is "lookbehind"; it asserts that `...` *does* appear *before* the cursor.

  ```
  1.9.3p125 :002 > 'four flour'.gsub(/(?<=f)our/, 'ive')
   => "five flour"
  ```

  The "our" in "four" matches because there's an "f" immediately before it, but the "our" in "flour" has an "l" immediately before it so it doesn't match.

  Like above, you have to be careful with what you put *before* it.  `a(?<=b)` will never match, because it checks that the next character is `a`, moves the cursor, then checks that the previous character was `b`.
- `(?!...)` is "negative lookahead"; it asserts that `...` *does not* appear after the cursor.

  ```
  1.9.3p125 :003 > 'child children'.gsub(/child(?!ren)/, 'kid')
   => "kid children"
  ```

  "child" matches, because what comes next is a space, not "ren".  "children" doesn't.

  This is probably the one I get the most use out of; finely controlling what can't come next comes in handy.
- `(?<!...)` is "negative lookbehind"; it asserts that `...` *does not* appear *before* the cursor.

  ```
  1.9.3p125 :004 > 'foot root'.gsub(/(?<!r)oot/, 'eet')
   => "feet root"
  ```

  The "oot" in "foot" is fine, since there's no "r" before it.  The "oot" in "root" clearly has an "r".

  As an additional restriction, most regex engines require that `...` has a fixed length in this case.  So you can't use `?`, `+`, `*`, or `{n,m}`.

You can also nest these and otherwise do all kinds of crazy things.  I use them mainly for one-offs I know I'll never have to maintain, so I don't have any great examples of real-world applications handy; honestly, they're weird enough that you should try to do what you want some other way first.  :)

---

Afterthought: The syntax comes from [Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), which used `(?` followed by various symbols for a lot of extended syntax because `?` on its own is invalid.  So `<=` doesn't mean anything by itself; `(?<=` is one entire token, meaning "this is the start of a lookbehind".  It's like how `+=` and `++` are separate operators, even though they both start with `+`.

They're easy to remember, though: `=` indicates looking forwards (or, really, "here"), `<` indicates looking backwards, and `!` has its traditional meaning of "not".

---

Regarding your later examples:

```
irb(main):002:0> "foresight".sub(/(?!s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresee"

irb(main):003:0> "foresight".sub(/ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresee"
```

Yes, these produce the same output.  This is that tricky bit with using lookahead:

1. The regex engine has tried some things, but they haven't worked, and now it's at `fores|ight`.
2. It checks `(?!s)`.  Is the character *after* the cursor `s`?  No, it's `i`!  So that part matches and the matching continues, but the cursor *doesn't move*, and we still have `fores|ight`.
3. It checks `ight`.  Does `ight` come after the cursor?  Well, yes, it does, so move the cursor: `foresight|`.
4. We're done!

The cursor moved over the substring `ight`, so that's the full match, and that's what gets replaced.

Doing `(?!a)b` is useless, since you're saying: the next character *must not* be `a`, and it *must* be `b`.  But that's the same as just matching `b`!

This can be useful sometimes, but you need a more complex pattern: for example, `(?!3)\d` will match any digit that isn't a 3.

This is what you want:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > "foresight".sub(/(?<!s)ight/, 'ee')
 => "foresight"
```

This asserts that `s` doesn't come *before* `ight`.

Comment: You can't match (arbitrarily) nested parentheses with lookarounds, either.

Comment: oh, duh, that's using capture recursion.  i'll think of a better example

Comment: this is as much explanation as i can think to give!  please tell me if you need anything else

Comment: You people gave me a lot's. This is my reference book for revision any time this concept. All in one place! :) Nice one it is. Every should take the concept begin from here! Mind blowing........... thank you very much friends. Just my last **EDIT** remains to be answered, which would give us another flavoure here if anyone answers that :) :)

Comment: Perfect! no more questions! Wanna to be your student dear :)

Answer (score 5):

Zero-width assertions are difficult to understand until you realize that regex matches *positions* as well as characters.

When you see the string "foo" you naturally read three characters. But, there are also four *positions*, marked here by pipes: "|f|o|o|". A lookahead or lookbehind (aka lookarounds) match a position where the character before or after match the expression.

The difference between a zero-width expression and other expressions is that the zero-width expression only matches (or "consumes") the position. So, for example:

```
/(app)apple/
```

will fail to match "apple" because it's trying to match "app" twice. But

```
/(?=app)apple/
```

will succeed because the lookahead is only matching the *position* where "app" follows. It doesn't actually match the "app" character, allowing the next expression to consume them.

**LOOKAROUND DESCRIPTIONS**

> **Positive Lookahead: `(?=s)`**
>
> > Imagine you are a drill sergeant and you are performing an inspection. You begin at the front of the line with the intention of walking past each private and ensuring they meet expectations. But, before doing so, you look ahead one by one to make sure they have lined up in the property order. The privates' names are "A", "B", "C", "D" and "E". `/(?=ABCDE)...../.match('ABCDE')`. Yep, they are all present and accounted for.
>
> **Negative Lookahead: `(?!s)`**
>
> > You perform the inspection down the line and are finally standing at private D. Now you are going to look ahead to make sure that "F" from the other company has not, yet again, accidentally slipped into the wrong formation. `/.....(?!F)/.match('ABCDE')`. Nope, he hasn't slipped in this time, so all is well.
>
> **Positive Lookbehind: `(?<=s)`**
>
> > After completing the inspection, the sergeant is at the end of the formation. He turns and scans back to make sure no one has snuck away. `/.....(?<=ABCDE)/.match('ABCDE')`. Yep, everyone is present and accounted for.
>
> **Negative Lookbehind: `(?<!s)`**
>
> > Finally, the drill sergeant takes one last look to make sure that privates A and B have not, once again, switched places (because they like KP). `/.....(?<!BACDE)/.match('ABCDE')`. Nope, they haven't, so all is well.

Comment: OMG! perfect -- that's the one i asked you people, more clearer than online materials which I browsed till now. Have you seen my last **EDIT**?

Comment: In your post I got the concept of what `Zero-width` actually means in Ruby `Regex`? and the `consuming` factor - what are really a good feed to the `Regexp` learner.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of a *zero-width assertion* is an expression that *consumes zero characters while matching*. For example, in this example,

```
"foresight".sub(/sight/, 'ee')
```

what is matched is

```
foresight
    ^^^^^
```

and thus the result would be

```
foreee
```

However, in this example,

```
"foresight".sub(/(?<=s)ight/, 'ee')
```

what is matched is

```
foresight
     ^^^^
```

and therefore the result would be

```
foresee
```

Another example of a zero-width assertion is the *word-boundary* character, `\b`. For example, to match a complete word, you might try surrounding the word with spaces, *e.g.*

```
"flight light plight".sub(/\slight\s/, 'dark')
```

to get

```
flightdarkplight
```

But you see how matching the spaces removes it during substitution? Using a word boundary gets around this problem:

```
"flight light plight".sub(/\blight\b/, 'dark')
```

The `\b` matches the beginning or end of a word, but does not actually match a character: it's *zero-width*.

Maybe the most succinct answer to your question is this: **Lookahead and lookbehind assertions are *one kind* of zero-width assertions. All lookahead and lookbehind assertions are zero-width assertions.**

---

Here are explanations of your examples:

```
irb(main):001:0> "foresight".sub(/(?!s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresee"
```

Above, you're saying, "Match where the *next* character is *not* an `s`, and then an `i`." This is *always* true for an `i`, since an `i` is never an `s`, so the substitution succeeds.

```
irb(main):002:0> "foresight".sub(/(?=s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresight"
```

Above, you're saying, "Match where the *next* character *is* an `s`, and then an `i`." This is *never* true, since an `i` is never an `s`, so the substitution fails.

```
irb(main):003:0> "foresight".sub(/(?<=s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresee"
```

Above, already explained. (This is the correct one.)

```
irb(main):004:0> "foresight".sub(/(?<!s)ight/, 'ee')
=> "foresight"
```

Above, should be clear by now. In this case, "firefight" would substitute to "firefee", but not "foresight" to "foresee".

Comment: `consumes zero characters` - what is consuming could you explain technically? How `Look-ahead` and `Look-behind` is happening technically and helps to generate such output with concept of `zero-width assertion` please show me. i am eager to see the things!

Comment: I think @Eevee has explained it best. I've added some examples to my answer to help you further.