# Regular Expression for partial match length - String similarity

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

Say I have the string "Torcellite" and another string "Tor" - the similarity length of these two strings is 3 since both of them begin with "Tor". Now another string "christmas" and "mas" would have a similarity of 0 since they do not begin with the same set of characters.

In both cases, the second string is a suffix of the first string.

A clearer example:

Length of string: 1 to 10^5

String: `abaabc`

Suffixes: `abaabc`, `baabc`, `aabc`, `abc`, `bc`, `c`

Similarity: `abaabc`, none, `a`, `ab`, none, none

Similarity Length: 6, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0

Answer: 6+0+1+2+0+0 = 9

I have an inefficient logic to find these partial suffixes matches using regex.

Algorithm:

- Find all the substrings of the given string.
- Make a pattern from the substrings of the suffixes.

  ```
  for(int i=1; i<substrings[i].length; i++) {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^"+substrings[i].substring(0, i));
      Matcher m = p.find(string); //the given string for which similarities need to be  calculated
      if(m.find())
          similaryLengths +=  i;
  }
  ```
- The complexity for this becomes roughly O(n^2) since I need to run through the string for suffixes and then the substrings for patterns.
- I've thought of using grouping in the pattern to find the groups but I'm unsure what the regex would look like. What I have in mind is for the very first substring is: `((((((a)b)a)a)b)c)` and then find the longest group match.

Is there a more efficient algorithm that can achieve his?

Comment: I am confused about why all your substrings are only suffixes - does 'baab' not also count as a substring?

Comment: @Valdar - sorry, I meant suffixes. Will correct it.

Comment: A couple of shortcuts (not regex-based): 1) the suffix which is the full string always adds a score of the length of the string, so that can be skipped; and 2) any suffix that doesn't start with the first char of the string adds zero and can be skipped.

Comment: @CarlManaster - Thanks Carl, I've implemented those. :)

Comment: When you say "In both cases, the second string is a suffix of the first string", how is it that "Tor" is a suffix of "Torcellite"?

Comment: @Brian - It's part of the suffix. I need to match the maximum possible length of a suffix to the original string.

Comment: Since you're doing nothing but substrings, why are you using regex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach, by far, would be to build a *suffix tree* on the input string. Building suffix trees takes only O(n) time where n is the length of the string. A suffix tree consists logically of a tree in which all the suffixes of the string can be found by walking from the root to each leaf. You can [read Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) for more details on how these trees work.

Essentially, a suffix tree will allow you to simply recast your current problem as one of "finding" the original string in the suffix tree. As you walk down the tree, you count the number of suffixes in each subtree, and multiply by your current match length to determine your score. This "search" takes O(n) time too.

So the final result is that you can solve the problem in *guaranteed* O(n) time and O(n) space, with O(n) preprocessing time. This is pretty efficient! And, there are no "worst cases" that produce quadratic behaviour. With that you can probably handle strings up to 10^7 in length easily.

The only difficulty in implementation will be building the suffix tree, but you can find freely available code for that.

Comment: Absolutely stunning. Maybe you could supply some examples to visualize the score counting during tree traversal; Wikipedia does not explain that part, and it is not so obvious _why_ this even works.

Comment: @nneonneo - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had a nagging feeling Regex was too complicated for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Simliar algorithm as already posted by Valdar Moridin, but without the need to create substrings (every call to `substring` will create a new `String` object that contains a copy of the specified range of the `char[]` of its source). This won't improve the time complexity, but probably reduces the total runtime for a constant factor:

```
public static int partialSuffixMatch(CharSequence input) {
    int count = input.length();
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        for (int a = 0, b = i; b < input.length(); a++, b++) {
            if (input.charAt(a) != input.charAt(b))
                break;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

After a short warmup, this algorithm processes a `String` with 10,000 equal characters in about 40 ms on my computer, and with 100,000 equal characters in about 4 seconds.

Comment: I like the fact that you've avoided substrings, however I guess this algorithm will be inefficient for anything higher than 100,000 characters? If I'm wrong, could you show me some actual output? I can't test the code currently.

Comment: I could process 100,000 chars in about 4 seconds after warmup (first run: 21 seconds). Seems reasonable as input length is 10 times longer than 10,000 chars, so time factor should be about 10x10.

Comment: The time limit is 4s for Java. Guess there's a better algorithm. :/

Comment: @Torcellite I assume, there is. Probably the partial match table of Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) is a hint for an almost linear solution.

Comment: @Torcellite But note that 4s is the very worst case. For every other case it runs significantly faster! I've tried a random sequence of 100,000 `a`s and `b`s, and time dropped to around 1-2 ms!

Comment: @isnot2bad Maybe, i could start from 1, and final results could be count = count + input.length(); (since when i=0, it's not necessary to do the checking)

Comment: This is possible but you will not notice the improvement. It reduces the total number of iterations for 100,000 chars worst case (n*n/2) from 5,000,000,000 to 4,999,900,000. This is 0.002% only!

Comment: @Holger yes, but as I already stated in my previous comment, this would just reduce the total number of iterations for about 0.002%. Too less to notice the difference. I believe there must be a far more performant solution using an approach similar to the 'partial match' table of the knuth-morris-pratt pattern match algorithm. This table is already almost what we need here.

Comment: @isnot2bad: I saw afterwards, that this was already discussed. However, since it’s unlikely to have the worst case (that would imply that all chars are equal), it could be an improvement in real scenarios.

Comment: @Holger I modified the code so that iteration now starts from 1 instead of 0. It will not cause a noteable difference in the worst case, but I agree, it might improve real world scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do what you've described above.  I don't know what this is supposed to accomplish, but since you've specified that only the start of the strings need to match, even though it's O(n^2), most of the time it will not be running for anywhere near the full length of n.  Worst case is obviously a string like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".  This takes less than 5 seconds to process a string of 60,000 'a' characters on my machine.

I don't see any need to involve the overhead of generating and compiling regular expressions for a strict prefix match.  Have I missed the point?

```
int similarity(String input) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() ; i++) {
        String sub = input.substring(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < sub.length(); j++) {
            if (input.charAt(j) != sub.charAt(j))
                break;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the length of the strings go up to 10^5.

Comment: I agree that regex is not needed for this algorithm, and will only hinder performance.

Answer (score 1):

From the `abaabc` example, I gather you are trying to find all substrings that match the start of the original string. This *can* be done with a single regular expression, a bit similar to the pattern you proposed. Of course, that regex will be proportional in length to the original string. The regex itself is very straightforward; it represents the entire string, but the string's tail (of arbitrary length) is optional. Effectively, this regex matches *any* prefix of the string. For a string `abcdef`, the regex is:

```
(?=(a(?:b(?:c(?:d(?:ef?)?)?)?)?))
```

Notes:

- I used `(?: ... )` for every subpattern except the outer one, to avoid a lot of unnecessary captures.
- I used the look-ahead pattern `(?= ... )` because matches can (and will) be overlapping. Without it, the very first match (being the entire string `abcdef`) will consume the entire input, causing all other possible matches to be skipped.

Of course, `abcdef` is not an interesting example; it has no repeating substrings, so the regex has only one match, which is the entire string, `abcdef`. Your example `abaabc` is nicer, so I made a fiddle for it. As pointed out by you, it finds 3 matches: abaabc, a, ab.
http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uQ9/1

Feel free to play around with it, but don't forget, for every change in the test string, you need to change the regex accordingly. For long strings, this becomes tedious. Fortunately, a simple recursive program can generate a regex for any given string.

```
function generateRegex(string input)
{
    return input.substring(0, 1) +
           (input.length > 2 ? "(?:" + generateRegex(input.substring(1)) + ")" : input.substring(1)) +
           "?";
}

string myRegex = "(?=(" + generateRegex(myInput) + "))";
```

I had no Java test environment at hand, but I did test it in JavaScript.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqehcjf9/1/

Performance seems OK (less than a second for a string of 9000 characters), but I did get a 'regular expression too complex' exception when testing against a string of more than 9361 characters (Firefox 31.0). I hope Java's regex engine is less restrictive. If not, then there's one possible optimization. If you are pretty sure that repeating substrings are never longer than, say, 1000 characters, then you might consider generating a regex for only the first 1000 characters of the string. You *will* be missing part of the first match (i.e. the entire string), but correcting that is a no-brainer.

Comment: Seems promising, I'll give it a go on Java and let you know the results.

Comment: The positive lookahead seems to do weird things in Java, or I just don't understand it. When `lookingAt` returns true, the end marker returns as index 0 when using lookAhead. If I remove the lookahead flag, the matcher will give proper information on what was matched.

Comment: @JBert: `m.end() - m.start()` is zero because the regex as a whole is a [zero-width assertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387631/how-the-look-ahead-and-look-behind-concept-supports-such-zero-width-assertions-c). Get the offsets of the first capturing subpattern instead: `m.end(1) - m.start(1)`. I must admit I didn't test it in Java; please let me know if behavior differs from my expectations.

Answer (score 0):

How does this perform on your dataset?

```
int sum = s.length;
for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < s.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < s.length - j; k++) {
            if (s.charAt(i+k) != s.charAt(j+k)) break;
            sum++;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of iterating i you could find the next occurrence of s.charAt(0).

Comment: This would be extremely slow. The dataset has strings of length 10^5.

Comment: Hm. Your algorithm returns 23 for the sample input "abaabc". But should be 9.

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly try the below methods. I have tested this one.
Any input string (length from 1~10^5), the execution time is less time **20ms** in my PC.

```
public static int oneTry(CharSequence input) {
    int tail = input.length();
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(0)) {
            tail = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    int count = 0;

    int head = 0;
    int next = 0;
    int base = 0;
    int two = -1;
    boolean start = false;
    boolean end = false;
    for (int i = tail; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(next)) {

            count++;

            if (next>0 && !start && input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(0)) {
                base = 1;
                start = true;
            }

            if (start) {
                if (!end && input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(head)) {
                    count = count + base;
                    head++;
                    head = head < tail ? head : 0;
                    if(head == 0) {
                        base++;
                    }
                } else {
                    end = true;
                }

                if(end) {
                    if(two <0 && input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(0)) {
                        two = i;
                    }
                }
            }

            next++;

            if(i==input.length()-1 && two > 0) {
                i = two - 1;

                next = 0;
                base = 0;
                two = -1;
                start = false;
                end = false;
                head = 0;
            }

        } else {
            if(two > 0) {
                i = two - 1;

                next = 0;
                base = 0;
                two = -1;
                start = false;
                end = false;
                head = 0;
            } else {
                if(end || !start) {
                    if(input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(0)) i--;

                    next = 0;
                    base = 0;
                    two = -1;
                    start = false;
                    end = false;
                    head = 0;
                } else {
                    i--;

                    next = next - tail;
                    base = base -1;
                    two = -1;
                    start = base==0 ? false : true;
                    end = false;
                    //head = 0;
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
    count = count + input.length();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This looks complex. Care to explain it? Also, what is the performance for a string like "ababababab...", where there are 50000 repeats of "ab"?

Comment: For the input string like "ababababab...", where there are 50000 repeats of "ab", the test results in my PC is 16ms. The performance increase is siginificant.
Acutally, my algorithm is very suitable for the first level repeatless(e.g.: aaa....,abab...,abcabc...,abcdabcd...). But for second or above level repeat, its cycle-count is similar as isnot2bad's. (e.g.: ababdababd...,abcabcdabcabcd...)
Meanwhile, the algorithm is to reduce the first level's repeat-count, just to increase the base value. I'm still thinking Is there any other good method which is suitable for all leverl's repeat.

Comment: then your program still has worst-case behaviour of quadratic time, no? What if I make a string of length 100000, with repeats of length 100?

Comment: @nneonneo Yes. The worst-case is "aabaabaab..." which is 'aab' repeat 33333 times. Then, the performance is nearly double time compared with isnot2bad's method. The second part depends on your repeats' pattern. If the pattern only contain one level repeat, then the performance is so goood. (e.g.: abbbcdeeeeefff....def, only one 'a' in it). if more than one, then the repeat length of first level is longer, then the performance is better. so "abbbddabbdd..." is bettern than "abbbabbb...". the worst is "aabaabaabaab..." in your 100-length repeats. FYI. Thanks.

Comment: @nneonneo In the worst case, although the cycle-count is the same as isnot2bad's method, the more checking in my every cycle will lead nearly double-times longer than isnot2bad's method. I think there should be one good method (which can be appled to all repeat patterns). Hope someone could find it. FYI.

Comment: Look at my solution. I absolutely guarantee that it is linear time, but the code is rather harder to write.

Comment: @nneonneo Very interesting & smart idea.(Using suffix tree) However, I'm a little bit doubt the whole performance (building the suffix tree + producing the final string similarity value). Hope someone could give us some test results & implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion, whatever method you choose to implement it, it normally will has its own worst case.
The difference is that the performance for its worst case.
For example, I have tested the isnot2bad's method , my first implementation(oneTry) & my second implemenation(secondTry) in my PC.
**The test results for worst case is:**
**isnot2bad's** method: ~330s (2*10^5), ~74s (10^5) , ~0.8 (10^4), ~0.01(10^3)
my first implementation(**oneTry**):~200s(2*10^5), ~ 45s(10^5) , ~0.5s(10^4), ~0.01(10^3)
my second implemenation(**secondTry**): ~4s (10^6), ~ 0.4s(10^5),~0.05s(10^4),~0.007(10^3)

From the test results, we can see the worst performance time for "secondTry" is **nearly linear** with string length, while others are **nearly square** with string length.

---

The idea for secondTry implementation is like this:
For any string input **T(T0...Tn-1, len=n),** the total string's similarity value(**St**) is the sum of every single char's similarity value(**Si**) among the string S.
      e.g.: St = S0 + ...+Si+...+Sn-1
Obviously, the total number of T0 in substring [T0...Ti]>= Si >=1
The exact value of Si is equal to the total number of T0 in substring [T0...Ti], which continues matching to Ti.
For example: T="aabaab", then T2='b', only T0('a') can continue to T2, while T1('a') can't continue to T2. Therefore, S2=1
Therefore, we need to keep track wich T0 is continued (if yes, keep it in the Array, if not, remove it from the Array). Then, it's easy to calculate every Ti's similarity.
Meanwhile, in order to improve the performance, we don't need to check every conitnuing T0. Acutally, for some T0, they can be combiled together.
Because they're belong to the repeat pattern.(it could be long pattern, or short pattern).
**For example:**
    ababababab...   : T0,T2,T4,T6... can be combied together as whole one.
    aaaaaaaaaa...   : T0,T1,T2,T3... can be combied together as whole one.
    aaaabaaaabaaaab...:
        T0,T5,T10,T15... can be combied together as whole one.
        T1,T2,T3 can be combied together as whole one.
        T6,T7,T8 can be combied together as whole one.
        ...

The detailed implementation code is shown as below.
Hope someone can post their best implementation & test results for this topic.
**Thanks.**

---

```
    public static List<ANode> anodes = null;
    public static List<ANode> tnodes = null;
    public static void checkANodes(CharSequence input, int num) {
        tnodes = new Vector<ANode>(); 
        for(int i=anodes.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            ANode anode = anodes.get(i);
            if(input.charAt(num) == input.charAt(num-anode.pos)) {
                tnodes.add(anode);
            }else {
                if(tnodes.size() > 0) {
                    // ok to do the changes
                    ANode after = tnodes.get(tnodes.size()-1);
                    tnodes.remove(after);
                    if(after.c > 1) {
                        tnodes.add(new ANode(after.pos + after.shift, after.shift ,after.c-1)); 
                        tnodes.add(new ANode(after.pos, after.pos-anode.pos + anode.shift,1));
                    }else {
                        tnodes.add(new ANode(after.pos, after.pos-anode.pos + anode.shift,1));  
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        anodes.clear();
        for(int i=tnodes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            anodes.add(tnodes.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static int secondTry(CharSequence input) {
        anodes = new Vector<ANode>();

        int start = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(0)) {
                start = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        int count = 0;
        int base = 0;
        for (int i = start; i < input.length(); i++) {
            checkANodes(input, i);
            if(input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(i)) {
                if(anodes.size() == 0) {
                    anodes.add(new ANode(i,  i, 1));
                }else {
                    ANode last = anodes.get(anodes.size()-1);
                    int shift = i - last.pos;
                    int mod = shift % last.shift;
                    if(mod == 0) {
                        last.c++;
                    }else {
                        anodes.add(new ANode(i, mod, 1));
                    }
                }
            }

            base = 0;
            for(ANode anode : anodes) {
                base = base + anode.c;
            }           
            count = count + base;
        }

        count = count + input.length();
        return count;
    }

public class ANode {
    public int pos = 0;
    public int c = 1;
    public int shift = 0;

    public ANode(int pos, int shift, int c) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.shift = shift;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```